# Why doesn't pynsist shortcut start python script?

Tags: python, pyqt5, nsis, pynsist

I recently tried to build an installer of a python application built with `PyQt5`. Unfortunately, after getting the installer via `.cfg` file and installing it on another computer the script does not start by clicking the shortcut in the (Windows) start menu.

When trying to start the Python-script directly by double-clicking it in the according folder of the installation, Python keeps crashing since `PyQt5` is not installed on the computer (although it can be found in the installation-folder). In case I manually install the package via `pip install PyQt5` it works when clicking on the script, but not when using the shortcut in the menu.

I suppose this could have to do with the automatically generated file path of the shortcut, but I could not find a solution how to fix it when building the installer. I used `script` instead of `entry_point` for it - could it be that this produces my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Here is what my `.cfg` script looks like:

```
[Application]
name=sample_name
version=V0.1
publisher=sample_publisher
script=C:\path to Python script\launch_script.pyw
icon=sample_icon.ico

[Python]
version=3.6.3

[Include]
pypi_wheels=PyQt5==5.10

files=folder_with_additional_scripts

[Build]
directory=build\
```

Comment: `entry_point` is strongly recommended if possible. Have a look at [the examples](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/tree/master/examples) to see how to use it. If you're using `script` instead, you need to ensure the script has at least the boilerplate [described in the docs](http://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cfgfile.html#application-section).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Solved the problem just a minute ago. Basically, it works when using script, but the actual mistake was to assume that `pynsist` would automatically install `PyQt5`. I had to include a section in the `Python` script that installs the package if not available on the computer. Now, everything works fine!

Comment: Pynsist should bundle PyQt5 so long as you're specifying it in the config file, which you are. But for the application to find it, you have to include `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'pkgs'))`. When you use `entry_point`, it does that for you.

Comment: Ah thanks, that works better than the pip command in the script! However, I'll switch to `entry_point` - that's the far better solution! Thanks for the suggestion!